# How can I access dimensions of labels plotted by `geom_text` in `ggplot2`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As far as I can see `ggplot2` *knows* the dimensions of labels plotted by `geom_text`. Otherwise the `check_overlap` option would not work.

**Where are these *dimensions* stored and how can I access them?**

---

Illustrative example

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), 
                 y = c(1, 1), 
                 label = c("label-one-that-might-overlap-another-label", 
                           "label-two-that-might-overlap-another-label"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With `check_overlap = FALSE` (the default), the labels overplot each other.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = label)) + 
  xlim(0, 3)
```

[image]

With `check_overlap = TRUE`, the second label is not plotted, because `ggplot` finds an overlap.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = label), check_overlap = TRUE) + 
  xlim(0, 3)
```

[image]

**How does `ggplot2` know that those labels overlap? How can I access that information?**

Comment: Based on the underlying code for `geom_text` [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/fa3cd8fbd4c904b7cd63687c8f7149e3abba0a4e/R/geom-text.r) and the previous discussion on the package's GH [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1039), the `check_overlap` parameter is passed to `grid::textGrob`, so I doubt you can find anything within `ggplot2` on this...

Comment: @Z.Lin: Thx for your comment. Do you have any idea or experience in how (and how easily) a custom `grob` could be designed and implemented? Do you understand how this is passed through in the current `geom_text` implementation. I didn't understand it when looking at the source of `grid::textGrob`..

Comment: I'm afraid not. I mess around with ggplot objects once in a while, but grid is a whole different story. What's your actual use case? It may be possible to find a non-grid workaround.

Comment: @Z.Lin My actual use case is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632173/how-can-i-cut-curves-drawn-by-geom-curve-in-order-they-dont-overlap-labels-pl) and a first possible workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688698/overplot-curve-by-another-curve-with-the-same-position-but-cutted-beginning-and)

Comment: Would placing the arrowhead in the middle of the line help in that case? It'll probably be easier to implement. Something like [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55123575/8449629), perhaps?

Comment: @Z.Lin: That could be a valuable workaround. Thx for the link and idea.

Answer (score 3):

Text in the grid package doesn't really have a size until it is time to draw the text. Below, we'll make a helper function to measure text, but it doesn't really make any sense to do this unless you know the device and size of the plotting area in advance. (For those in the know, during the `makeContent()` stage of drawing).

```r
library(grid)

label <- c("label-one-that-might-overlap-another-label", 
           "label-two-that-might-overlap-another-label")

measure_size <- function(txt, gp = gpar(), to = "mm") {
  if (is.grob(txt)) {
    grobs <- lapply(seq_along(txt$label), function(i) {
      g <- txt
      # Subset grob per label
      g$label <- g$label[[i]]
      g$gp[]  <- lapply(g$gp, function(x) {x[pmin(i, length(x))]})
      g$rot   <- g$rot[pmin(i, length(g$rot))]
      g
    })
  } else {
    grobs <- lapply(txt, function(t) textGrob(t, gp = gp))
  }
  
  heights <- do.call(unit.c, lapply(grobs, grobHeight))
  widths  <- do.call(unit.c, lapply(grobs, grobWidth))
  
  cbind(
    height = convertHeight(heights, to, valueOnly = TRUE),
    weight = convertWidth(widths,   to, valueOnly = TRUE)
  )
}
```

We can now try to guess the size of the text as best as we can, but as one might expect, it depends a lot on graphical parameters of text what the actual size is. Notice for example that changing the font also changes the size of the text.

```r
measure_size(label)
#>      height   weight
#> [1,]  3.175 79.13109
#> [2,]  3.175 78.65566

measure_size(label, gp = gpar(fontfamily = "Garamond"))
#>        height   weight
#> [1,] 2.645833 69.67223
#> [2,] 2.645833 69.69704
```

Now applying the same trick to ggplot2's text layer.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.1

df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), 
                 y = c(1, 1), 
                 label = label)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = label)) + 
  xlim(0, 3) 

textgrob <- layer_grob(p)[[1]]
measure_size(textgrob)
#>        height   weight
#> [1,] 2.645979 72.83233
#> [2,] 2.645979 72.39411
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I worked a lot with text recently myself and found that the {systemfonts}/{textshaping} packages accurately return the size of the text in pixels, which is of course device/resolution dependent.

```r
systemfonts::string_width("My label")
#> [1] 46
textshaping::text_width("My label")
#> [1] 46
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are just looking to avoid overlapping labels, the ggrepel package works pretty well.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), 
                 y = c(1, 1), 
                 label = c("label-one-that-might-overlap-another-label", 
                           "label-two-that-might-overlap-another-label"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = label), check_overlap = F) + 
  xlim(0, 3)
```

The above code produces the graph below. 
[image]