# Control padding of grobs added to patchwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob, patchwork

This is a follow up problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66918748/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-size-layout-of-a-single-plot-to-match-a-certain/66925859?noredirect=1#comment118459345_66925859). The OP asked for a way to arrange parts of a plot in specific distances. I think teunbrand gave a very good answer.

My own suggestion (extract the legend with cowplot, and stitch them to a plot in desired proportions) is not fully satisfactory, because it worked only "by chance" in the given example - the legend labels were long enough to center the legend grob into the viewport for the third plot.

Having shorter labels reveals the problem - when adding a grob, patchwork centres this grob, basically padding equally to all sides.

My question is, do you know of a way to control this padding behaviour?

Cowplot (or any other ggplot combining package for that sake) also very welcome.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
data <- midwest %>% 
  head(5) %>% 
  select(2,23:25) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=2:4,names_to="Variable", values_to="Percent") %>% 
  mutate(Variable=factor(Variable, 
                         levels=c("percbelowpoverty","percchildbelowpovert","percadultpoverty"),
                         labels = paste0("perc", 1:3)))

p1 <- 
  ggplot(data=data, mapping=aes(x=county, y=Percent, fill=Variable)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CF232B","#942192","#000000")) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey50"))

p_legend <- cowplot::get_legend(p1)

p_main <- p1 <- 
  ggplot(data=data, mapping=aes(x=county, y=Percent, fill=Variable)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CF232B","#942192","#000000"))

p_main + plot_spacer() + p_legend + 
  plot_layout(widths = c(12.5, 1.5, 4)) &
  theme(plot.margin = margin(),
        plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

<sub>Not so desired result - the legend grob (with grey background) should be aligned to the left plot border (black line)</sub>

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I get it the issue is not on `patchwork`s side. Having a look at the layout of the legend's `gtable` we see that it is made up of 5 rows and 5 columns and that the legend is to be placed in the cell in the center:

```r
p_legend <- cowplot::get_legend(p1)
p_legend
#> TableGrob (5 x 5) "guide-box": 2 grobs
#>                                     z     cells                  name
#> 99_a788e923bf245af3853cee162f5f8bc9 1 (3-3,3-3)                guides
#>                                     0 (2-4,2-4) legend.box.background
#>                                               grob
#> 99_a788e923bf245af3853cee162f5f8bc9 gtable[layout]
#>                                     zeroGrob[NULL]
gtable::gtable_show_layout(p_legend)
```

[image]

Hence, when adding the legend `patchwork` centers is as demanded by the `gtable` layout.

One option to control the positioning or the padding of the legend would be to squash the first column via `cowplot::gtable_squash_cols` and if desired add some padding by adding a new column with the desired amount of padding via `gtable::gtable_add_cols`:

```r
# Squash first column
p_legend <- cowplot::gtable_squash_cols(p_legend, 1)
# Add some padding by adding a new col
p_legend <- gtable::gtable_add_cols(p_legend, unit(.1, "cm"), pos = 1)

p_main <- p1 <- 
  ggplot(data=data, mapping=aes(x=county, y=Percent, fill=Variable)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CF232B","#942192","#000000"))

p_main + plot_spacer() + p_legend + 
  plot_layout(widths = c(12.5, 1.5, 4)) &
  theme(plot.margin = margin(),
        plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: that's wonderful. Thanks, Stefan. As a matter of fact, the added padding after the squash isn't necessary for this purpose - `p_legend <- gtable_squash_cols(get_legend(p1), 1)` should suffice

Comment: Really clever by the way. I was just not thinking of exploring underlying gtable to p_legend. I was almost going to submit a feature request in patchwork lol. Thanks for saving me from that

Comment: Hi @tjebo. You are welcome. That was a very interesting and useful question. And a very good opportunity to dive a bit deeper into ggplot manipulation via gtable, cowplot, ... Best S.