# Fixed width of legend box using ggplot, gtable and cowplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, gtable

I would like to make a plot with R that looks like the sample made with Mac's Numbers. I'm struggling with the space between the plot and the legend box. This is a sample of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

With the help of some users (see end of post for reference) I got really close already. This is my current function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
library(gtable)
library(grid)
library(patchwork)


custom_barplot <- function(dataset, x_value, y_value, fill_value, nfill, xlab, ylab, y_limit, y_steps,legend_labels) {
# Example color set to choose from
colors=c("#CF232B","#942192","#000000","#f1eef6","#addd8e","#d0d1e6","#31a354","#a6bddb")

# user function for adjusting the size of key-polygons in legend
draw_key_polygon2 <- function(data, params, size) {
  lwd <- min(data$size, min(size) / 4)
  
  grid::rectGrob(
    width = grid::unit(0.8, "npc"),
    height = grid::unit(0.8, "npc"),
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour,
      fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha),
      lty = data$linetype,
      lwd = lwd * .pt,
      linejoin = "mitre"
    ))
}
# user function for the plot itself
plot <- function(dataset, x_value, y_value, fill_value, nfill, xlab, ylab, y_limit, y_steps,legend,legend_labels) 
{ggplot(data=dataset, mapping=aes(x={{x_value}}, y={{y_value}}, fill={{fill_value}})) +
    geom_col(position=position_dodge(width=0.85),width=0.8,key_glyph="polygon2",show.legend=legend) + 
    geom_smooth(aes(color={{fill_value}}),method="lm",formula=y~x, se=FALSE,show.legend=legend, linetype="dashed") +
    labs(x=xlab,y=ylab) +
    theme(text=element_text(size=9,color="black"),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"),
          panel.grid = element_line(color = "black",linetype="solid",size= 0.3),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text=element_text(size=9),
          axis.line.x=element_line(color="black"),
          axis.ticks= element_blank(),
          legend.text=element_text(size=9),
          legend.position = "right",
          legend.justification = "top",
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.key.size = unit(4,"mm"),
          legend.key = element_rect(fill="white"),
          plot.margin=unit(c(1,0.25,0.5,0.5),"cm")) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks= seq(from=0, to=y_limit,by=y_steps),
                       limits=c(0,y_limit+1), 
                       expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=min(data[,deparse(ensym(x_value))],na.rm=TRUE):max(data[,deparse(ensym(x_value))],na.rm=TRUE)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = colors[1:nfill],labels={{legend_labels}})+
    scale_color_manual(values= colors[1:nfill],labels=paste("Trend ",{{legend_labels}},sep=""))+
    guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA),order=2),fill=guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=0),order=1))}

# taking the legend of the plot and removing the first column of the gtable within the legend
p_legend <- #cowplot::get_legend(plot(dataset, {{x_value}}, {{y_value}}, {{fill_value}}, nfill, xlab, ylab, y_limit, y_steps,legend=TRUE))
  gtable_squash_cols(cowplot::get_legend(plot(dataset, {{x_value}}, {{y_value}}, {{fill_value}},nfill, xlab, ylab, y_limit, y_steps,legend=TRUE,legend_labels)),1)

# printing the plot without legend
p_main <- plot(dataset, {{x_value}}, {{y_value}}, {{fill_value}}, nfill, xlab, ylab, y_limit, y_steps,legend=FALSE,legend_labels = NULL)

#joining it all together
Obj<- p_main+plot_spacer() + p_legend +
  plot_layout(widths=c(12.5,1.5,4))

return(Obj)

}
```

My problem is, that the width of the legend box seems to adjust to the size of the labels, so the distance between the plot and the legend does not remain the same.

Example Data:

```
set.seed(9)
data <- data.frame(Cat=c(rep("A",times=5),rep("B",times=5),rep("C", times=5)),
                   year=rep(c(2015,2016,2017,2018,2019),times=3),
                   count=c(sample(seq(60,80),replace=TRUE,size=5),sample(seq(100,140),replace=TRUE,size=5),sample(seq(20,30),replace=TRUE,size=5)))
```

I made four plots where only the labels are different:

```
plt <- custom_barplot(dataset=data %>% filter(year %in% c(2015,2016,2017)), 
     x_value=year,
     y_value=count, 
     fill_value=Cat, 
     nfill=3, 
     xlab="Year",
     ylab="Count",
     y_limit=140, 
     y_steps=20,
     legend_labels=c("A","B","C"))


plt_2 <- custom_barplot(dataset=data %>% filter(year %in% c(2015,2016,2017)), 
                        x_value=year,
                        y_value=count, 
                        fill_value=Cat, 
                        nfill=3, 
                        xlab="Year",
                        ylab="Count",
                        y_limit=140, 
                        y_steps=20,
                        legend_labels=c("Long Label A","Long Label B","Long Label C"))

plt_3 <- custom_barplot(dataset=data %>% filter(year %in% c(2015,2016,2017)), 
                        x_value=year,
                        y_value=count, 
                        fill_value=Cat, 
                        nfill=3, 
                        xlab="Year",
                        ylab="Count",
                        y_limit=140, 
                        y_steps=20,
                        legend_labels=c("Xtra Long Label A","Xtra Long Label B","Xtra Long Label C"))

plt_4 <- custom_barplot(dataset=data %>% filter(year %in% c(2015,2016,2017)), 
                        x_value=year,
                        y_value=count, 
                        fill_value=Cat, 
                        nfill=3, 
                        xlab="Year",
                        ylab="Count",
                        y_limit=140, 
                        y_steps=20,
                        legend_labels=c("Super Xtra Long Label A","Super Xtra Long Label B","Super Xtra Long Label C"))
```

The resulting plots look like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I need the space between the plot and the legend to be constant, nevermind the length of the labels in the legend. I'd rather have that label is not fully displayed (so I see I have to shorten it). The graphs are used in documents with *tufte handout style* and the legend should be in the same area as annotations will be.

Do you have any idea how to keep the space constant?

*Reference:*

- Basic method by [tjebo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66925859/14027466) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66918748/14027466)
- General adjustment of space between plot and legend by [stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67029094/14027466) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67026849/14027466)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the text (i.e. adding linebreaks) for the different items in the legend? By forcing width of the text to be less than a certain number of characters you might eliminate some of the friction. You might try this using `stringr::str_wrap()` or the base function `strwrap()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to simply apply wrapping to the text in your legend. You can do this using `stringr::str_wrap()` to give results like the following:

[image: plot 1]
[image: plot 2]
[image: plot 3]
[image: plot 4]

Here is a very minimal edit to your function which allows a user to control the text wrapping:

```
custom_barplot <- function(dataset, x_value, y_value, fill_value, nfill, xlab, ylab, y_limit, y_steps, legend_labels, wrap_labels = 20) {
  # Example color set to choose from
  colors <- c("#CF232B", "#942192", "#000000", "#f1eef6", "#addd8e", "#d0d1e6", "#31a354", "#a6bddb")

  # user function for adjusting the size of key-polygons in legend
  draw_key_polygon2 <- function(data, params, size) {
    lwd <- min(data$size, min(size) / 4)

    grid::rectGrob(
      width = grid::unit(0.8, "npc"),
      height = grid::unit(0.8, "npc"),
      gp = grid::gpar(
        col = data$colour,
        fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha),
        lty = data$linetype,
        lwd = lwd * .pt,
        linejoin = "mitre"
      )
    )
  }
  # user function for the plot itself
  plot <- function(dataset, x_value, y_value, fill_value, nfill, xlab, ylab, y_limit, y_steps, legend, legend_labels) {
    ggplot(data = dataset, mapping = aes(x = {{ x_value }}, y = {{ y_value }}, fill = {{ fill_value }})) +
      geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.85), width = 0.8, key_glyph = "polygon2", show.legend = legend) +
      geom_smooth(aes(color = {{ fill_value }}), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, show.legend = legend, linetype = "dashed") +
      labs(x = xlab, y = ylab) +
      theme(
        text = element_text(size = 9, color = "black"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid = element_line(color = "black", linetype = "solid", size = 0.3),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 9),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.justification = "top",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(4, "mm"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5), "cm")
      ) +
      scale_y_continuous(
        breaks = seq(from = 0, to = y_limit, by = y_steps),
        limits = c(0, y_limit + 1),
        expand = c(0, 0)
      ) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = min(data[, deparse(ensym(x_value))], na.rm = TRUE):max(data[, deparse(ensym(x_value))], na.rm = TRUE)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = colors[1:nfill], labels = stringr::str_wrap({{ legend_labels }}, wrap_labels)) +
      scale_color_manual(values = colors[1:nfill], labels = stringr::str_wrap(paste("Trend ", {{ legend_labels }}, sep = ""), wrap_labels)) +
      guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA), order = 2), fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0), order = 1))
  }

  # taking the legend of the plot and removing the first column of the gtable within the legend
  p_legend <- # cowplot::get_legend(plot(dataset, {{x_value}}, {{y_value}}, {{fill_value}}, nfill, xlab, ylab, y_limit, y_steps,legend=TRUE))
    gtable_squash_cols(cowplot::get_legend(plot(dataset, {{ x_value }}, {{ y_value }}, {{ fill_value }}, nfill, xlab, ylab, y_limit, y_steps, legend = TRUE, legend_labels)), 1)

  # printing the plot without legend
  p_main <- plot(dataset, {{ x_value }}, {{ y_value }}, {{ fill_value }}, nfill, xlab, ylab, y_limit, y_steps, legend = FALSE, legend_labels = NULL)

  # joining it all together
  Obj <- p_main + plot_spacer() + p_legend +
    plot_layout(widths = c(12.5, 1.5, 4))

  return(Obj)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this post. I just played around with the information you gave in the comment to the question and did not succeed. I did use the `word_wrap()` within the arguments when calling the plot function, though. E.g. `legend_labels=c(str_wrap("Long Label A",width=18),str_wrap("Long Label B",width=18),str_wrap("Long Label C",width=18))` I will look further into your solution, especially how I can retain the legend key for the bars as a square rather than a rectangle when the label text requires two lines.

Comment: I opened another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67734968/14027466) for adjusting the legend keys with wrapped texts, in case your interested.