# Automatically leave enough room for a label next to a barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a horizontal bar plot with `ggplot2`, with labels to the right of the bars. Hoe do I leave enough room for the labels so they don't fall off the chart?

This question has been asked many times before, but my question is about **automatically**, that means without manual adjusting, the space next to a barplot to leave enough room for labels.

The use case is a shiny app where:

- we don't know the width of the bars ahead of time
- we don't know the length of the text labels
- we don't know the text size

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  weight = c("short","longer label","medium lab"),
  speed = sample(50:150,3)
)

ggplot(data, aes(x = weight, y = speed, label = weight)) +
  coord_flip(clip = 'off') +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(hjust = -0.1, size = 4) +
  ylim(c(0, 1.07 * max(data$speed)))
```

Re-run the code and you will see that the label sometimes falls off the chart on the right).

My solution so far which "kind of" works is to have some estimator for the `ylim` multiplier (here, 1.07) to leave enough room. I can of course use a really high value but then we create too much whitespace.

I have also attempted to calculate the width of the grob via `grid::grobWidth`, largely based on this post:
[How can I access dimensions of labels plotted by `geom_text` in `ggplot2`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686910/how-can-i-access-dimensions-of-labels-plotted-by-geom-text-in-ggplot2)

However in order to calculate the actual size of a text (or other) element with this approach we need to know `cex` in `gpar`, but we only have a `size` argument in `geom_text`. I don't see how they are related (?).

I have also looked at `ggprepel` and its internal code but cannot understand how to apply their methods to this particular problem.

Any help / pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can measure the panel, the panel range and the text size using various tools from `grid` and `ggplot2`. This allows a recalculation of the upper limit required in your plot.

We can fit this into a function as follows:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

fix_labels <- function(p) {
  tl <- which(sapply(p$layers, function(x) any(grepl("Text", class(x$geom)))))
  g <- ggplot_build(p)
  range <- g$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range
  dat <- g$data[[tl]][order(factor(g$data[[tl]]$label)),]
  label_pos <- dat$x
  labels <- dat$label
  
  str_width <- sapply(labels, function(x) {
    textGrob(x, gp = gpar(fontsize = p$layers[[tl]]$aes_params$size * .pt)) |>
      grobWidth() |>
      convertWidth("cm", TRUE)
  })
  
  panel_width <- (unit(1, 'npc') - sum(ggplotGrob(p)$widths[-5])) |>
         convertWidth('cm', TRUE)
  
  units_per_cm <- diff(range) / panel_width
  
  new_x <- str_width * units_per_cm + label_pos 
  
  expansion_factor <- (max(new_x) - min(range))/diff(range)
  xval <- expansion_factor^2 * (max(new_x) - max(label_pos)) + max(label_pos)
  
  p + xlim(NA, xval)
}
```

We can test this on your own example, but we should modernize your code by removing the unnecessary `coord_flip` and change the `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` to the equivalent `geom_col()`.

We will also use a random seed for reproducibility, and a larger font size to illustrate the problem.

```r
set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  weight = c("short","longer label","medium lab"),
  speed = sample(50:150,3)
)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = speed, y = weight, label = weight)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(hjust = -0.1, size = 8) 

p
```

[image]

But now we can just do:

```
fix_labels(p)
```

[image]

This seems to work just as well with small text (here just the same code but with text size 4):

[image]

And even pointlessly large labels (here size 16)

[image]

Comment: Really nice, Allan. But what  is `pan`? Just tried to run your code but ... (:

Comment: @stefan oops - missed a line of code. Now added

Comment: It is not 100% correct though : with lower `size` there seems to be too much space, and if I make size = 14 (super larger), the text still does not fit. But it is certainly close, so I wonder if there is a small change to be made somewhere.

Comment: I think I see what the problem is. Adding to the x limits effectively makes the units per mm smaller (since there are more units to fit in the same space on the x axis). This means that once the plot is redrawn, the extra space is no longer adequate. This is more pronounced for larger text and longer strings. I'll have a look at this more closely and fix it @RemkoDuursma

Comment: I now tested the updated function in our larger application and it works perfectly. One small thing: when there are missing values in the x aesthetic, the calculations are off. Useful to know if you are using this function.