# How to Ensure That All Letters of geom_text Fit the ggplot2 Box

Tags: r, ggplot2, rasterizing

The simlified issue is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(x=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), nms = c("A","B","C","D","E")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=nms)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = x), 
            vjust = 0.5, hjust = -0.1, color = "gray")
```

[image]

As it is seen here the digits of the `geom_text` are not displayed for certain values. I manually set the limits for the x axis for instance by adding `+ scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,11000))`. But it seems not a good practice as the value of the upper limit is set randomly. Scaling up the upper limit by for example 10% `max(x)*1.1` is not a solution asd well as `10%` is a random number especially if it is expected that log trans can be added (or not added) to the x scale depending upon the specific values for different datasets used for the same visualisation and thus it does not take into account the width of the printed text label.

So my question is: what is the proper solution to add these `geom_text` geoms?

Comment: Don't think there is an easy or "proper" approach. But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098826/automatically-leave-enough-room-for-a-label-next-to-a-barplot/75099898#75099898 for an approach to automatically adjust the limits.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of definig the limits manualy you could use the expand arg. The default is 5% on each side so `expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.1))` should do the trick.

```r
data.frame(x=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), nms = c("A","B","C","D","E")) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=x, y=nms)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = x), 
              vjust = 0.5, hjust = -0.1, color = "gray") + 
    scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05,0.1)))
```

[image]

We could make the text go "inward" with `hjust = "inward"`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(x=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), nms = c("A","B","C","D","E")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=nms)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = x), 
            vjust = 0.5, hjust = "inward", color = "gray")
```

[image]

Or we could turn off clip with `coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')`

```r
data.frame(x=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), nms = c("A","B","C","D","E")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=x, y=nms)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = x), 
            vjust = 0.5, hjust = -0.1, color = "gray")+
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

[image]

It may be necessary to adjust plot margins.

```r
data.frame(x=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), nms = c("A","B","C","D","E")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=nms)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = x), 
            vjust = 0.5, hjust = -0.1, color = "gray") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1),'cm')) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>